# Online Ruby editor outputs error “undefined method `chomp'” about gets.chomp

Tags: ruby

Usually when editing with Ruby I never would have to identify `.chomp` but now it needs me to define it and I don’t know how to define it properly to work the same way.

Code:

```rb
print "What's you're name?"
first_name= gets.chomp
print "What's you're last name?"
last_name= gets.chomp
print "What city are you from?"
city= gets.chomp
print "want to know you're name backwards?"
    yes = true
    no = false
if yes
    puts #{first_name.reverse}
else
    puts "Ok!"
    print "you're first name is" #{first_name!}
    print "you're last name is" #{last_name!}
    print "you're city is" #{city!}
end
```

Editor:

https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-ruby-online/

I believe this may be an editor issue but please correct me if I’m wrong.

I was trying to make a questionnaire that takes the input then at the end spits it back out and asks if you would like to see your name backwards but instead I got an error I did not finish the other bit where it takes the information and spits it back out so ignore that. At first it just told me that chomp was not defined when using `gets.chomp` to take the input
but I never have to define `.chomp` before – this is a first. Please explain how to fix.

The error as seen in my code’s output:

```
What's you're name?
jdoodle.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, did you put anything in the box labeled "Stdin Inputs"? If there's nothing there, then `gets` returns `nil`, which does not in fact have a `chomp` method.

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner i did not know

Comment: What do I put in the stdin inputs to make it work?

Comment: That's where the program is going to get your input from. So you should put whatever you want `gets` to return. The online editor you've chosen isn't an interactive shell; it reads input from that textbox non-interactively.

Comment: To expand a bit the explanation by Silvio: In the way you use `gets` , you are basically calling the `gets` method of the module `Kernel`, which is described [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Kernel.html#method-i-gets). As you see, it retrieves its input from one of many possible sources, one of them is the _standard input_  from your program. The concept of standard input will follow you in virtually all programming languages and you better get familiar to it, see  [here](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/aixuser/usrosdev/std_input_output.htm)